# Vue.js with laravel 5.3

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, vue.js, vue-resource

I'm using Laravel 5.3 with Vue.js(very new to this).
Here's my current code

app.js

```
var vm = new Vue({
    el: '#app',

    data:  {
            messages: []
    },

    ready: function(){

        this.getMessages();
    },


    methods: {

        getMessages: function(){
                this.$http.get('api/messages').then((response) => {
                    this.$set('messages', data);
                        }, (response) => {
                });
        }
    }
});
```

api.php route is very simple

```
Route::get('/messages', function() {
     return Message::latest()->get();
    });
```

Note: here when i try access the route directly as localhost:8000/api/messages i get the array with the full data

On my view i have

```
<div class="content"   id="app">
                <tr v-for="message in messages">
                    <td> @{{ message}} </td>
                </tr>
</div>
```

I have included online libraries for all jquery, vue.js, and vue.resource.
When i use vue.js debugger it shows that it returns `messages[]` but it's empty.
I have followed a lot of examples but couldn't get it to work. 
Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2):

if you are using vue.js 2.0 , ready is deprecated now, you may use mounted instead

```
mounted: function () {
  this.$nextTick(function () {
    this.getMessages();
  })
}
```

[Vue.js Docs](http://vuejs.org/guide/migration.html#ready-deprecated)

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using the arrow syntax, then I switched to full ES2015 Code

```
getMessages() {

    this.$http.get('api/messages')
      .then( result => {
       this.messages = result.json() 
      })

}
```

Comment: Belmin. Thanks so much for your response. i tried and it still returned empty. but i kind of find a solution perhaps not the best. I was using vue.js version 2.0.1, once i changed it to older version 1.0.2 it worked.

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't work with VueJS 2.0 yet, so probabbly something in API is changed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var vm = new Vue({
    el: '#app',

    data:  {
            messages: []
    },

    ready: function(){

        this.getMessages();
    },


    methods: {

        getMessages: function(){
                let ctrl = this;
                this.$http.get('api/messages').then((response) => {
                    this.messages = response.data;
                });
        }
    }
});
```